# Kyocera printer: "using functions remotely"

Tags: printing, printer

How can I troubleshoot my printer constantly activating itself? It starts some warmup or something, and just writes "**using functions remotely**", and then shuts down again. It doesn't matter if it is sleep or awake.

It is a network printer, Kyocera Ecosys m5521cdw, and it's the same behavior, regardless of it's wireless-connected or with a network cable.

Edit: this is on my home network, but I don't have fancy gear to intercept traffic with. I guess I probably could set up something like that, but it'd probably be faster to just shut down all computers around the house and then bring them back one by one.

Comment: Depending on how the driver was written, simply opening an application that can print (like Word) can force the print driver to load.  This could be from anyone allowed to print to that printer.  That print driver might very well "reach out" to the printer to check status which would force this "warming up" behavior.  I have written over 180 printer drivers for Windows through the years.  Even though this ***is only a guess***, it is an educated one.

Comment: Is this your home network? If you wanted proof which device is to blame and you have sophisticated infrastructure, you could capture traffic to the printer, perhaps in a rolling buffer, and check the record when it happens.